# What is the range of the Weierstrass elliptic function?

Tags: elliptic-functions

There is the following function:
$$
\wp(z,\Lambda):=\frac{1}{z^2} + \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda\setminus\{0\}}\left(\frac 1 {(z-\lambda)^2} - \frac 1 {\lambda^2}\right)
$$
What values can it take? For me it seems like it smoothly sweeps through the whole complex plane while it reaches infinity. It could be a certain shape how it stretches between zero and infinity, but as I see it covers the whole complex plane. Is it true? I did not find anything about what is the map of the fundamental region of this function.

Comment: The range of all (nonconstant) elliptic functions is $\Bbb C \cup \{ \infty \}$.

Comment: Every elliptic function takes all values at least once